# gradient descent MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, gradient

So I wrote the following MATLAB code as an exercise for **gradient descent**. I obviously chose a function which has a minimum at (0,0), but the algorithm throws me to (-3,3).

I did find out that switching between `xGrad` and `yGrad` on line: `[xGrad,yGrad] = gradient(f);` grants the correct convergence, despite the fact that `xGrad`, `yGrad` are approximately `2*X`, `2*Y` as expected. I guess I inverted something here, but I've been trying to figure out what it is for some time now and I don't get it, so I hoped somebody can notice my mistake...

```
dx=.01;
dy=.01;
x=-3:dx:3;
y=-3:dy:3;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

f=X.^2+Y.^2;

lr = .1; %learning rate
eps = 1e-10; %epsilon threshold
tooMuch = 1e5; %limit iterations
p = [.1 1]; %starting point
[~, idx] = min( abs(x-p(1)) ); %index of closest value
[~, idy] = min( abs(y-p(2)) ); %index of closest value
p = [x(idx) y(idy)]; %closest point to start
[xGrad,yGrad] = gradient(f); %partial derivatives of f
xGrad = xGrad/dx; %scale correction
yGrad = yGrad/dy; %scale correction

for i=1:tooMuch %prevents too many iterations    
    fGrad = [ xGrad(idx,idy) , yGrad(idx,idy) ]; %gradient's definition
    pTMP = p(end,:) - lr*fGrad; %gradient descent's core
    [~, idx] = min( abs(x-pTMP(1)) ); %index of closest value
    [~, idy] = min( abs(y-pTMP(2)) ); %index of closest value
    p = [p;x(idx) y(idy)]; %add the new point
    if sqrt( sum( (p(end,:)-p(end-1,:)).^2 ) ) < eps %check conversion
        break
    end
end
```

Thanks to anyone who helps

edit: corrected typos and made the code clearer. It still does the same thing and has the same problem

Comment: Tangential comment:  It's unusual to precompute the gradient on a grid like this.  I think you shouldn't work on a grid.  It will simplify the code considerably and also be more correct and give better results.

Comment: I do show it in the end as an arrow diagram (using `quiver`), but if you can show me a way to compute the gradient more accurately I'll be happy (perhaps by a link to some documentation of it)

Comment: I assume this is mostly for learning purposes. For a problem like this, there's no need to grid everything out. You can keeping track of x_val and y_val without indices, grids, etc... and compute the gradient by taking partial derivatives yourself: `fGrad = [2*x_val, 2*y_val]`. For many functions, you can actually compute the gradient automatically using automatic differentiation (there are some packages for this).

Comment: I need it to run for more than that function, e.g I later check convergence of `-20*(X/2-X.^2-Y.^5)*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2)`. So it's better working for a general function in my opinion

Comment: If you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox then I suggest using something like `funstr='-20*(X/2-X^2-Y^5)*exp(-X^2-Y^2)'; syms X Y; mygrad=matlabFunction([diff(funstr,X) diff(funstr,Y)]);` to compute the gradient of your symbolic function. Note the lack of periods in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I didn't figure out what was wrong with the previous method, but here's an alternative script for gradient decent, which I used for the same question:

```
syms x y
f = -20*(x/2-x^2-y^5)*exp(-x^2-y^2); %cost function
% f = x^2+y^2; %simple test function

g = gradient(f, [x, y]);
lr = .01; %learning rate
eps = 1e-10; %convergence threshold
tooMuch = 1e3; %iterations' limit
p = [1.5 -1]; %starting point
for i=1:tooMuch %prevents too many iterations
    pGrad = [subs(g(1),[x y],p(end,:)) subs(g(2),[x y],p(end,:))]; %computes gradient
    pTMP = p(end,:) - lr*pGrad; %gradient descent's core
    p = [p;double(pTMP)]; %adds the new point
    if sum( (p(end,:)-p(end-1,:)).^2 ) < eps %checks convergence
        break
    end
end
v = -3:.1:3; %desired axes
[X, Y] = meshgrid(v,v);
contour(v,v,subs(f,[x y],{X,Y})) %draws the contour lines 
hold on
quiver(v,v,subs(g(1), [x y], {X,Y}),subs(g(2), [x y], {X,Y})) %draws the gradient directions 
plot(p(:,1),p(:,2)) %draws the route
hold off
suptitle(['gradient descent route from ',mat2str(round(p(1,:),3)),' with \eta=',num2str(lr)])
if i<tooMuch
    title(['converged to ',mat2str(round(p(end,:),3)),' after ',mat2str(i),' steps'])
else
    title(['stopped at ',mat2str(round(p(end,:),3)),' without converging'])
end
```

just some of the results

[image]

[image]

In the latter case you can see it doesn't converge, but it's not a problem with *gradient descent*, just learning rate set too high (so it misses the minimum point repeatedly).

feel welcome to use it.

Comment: While we're waiting for the 48-hour grace period after which you can accept your own answer, please consider uploading the images directly to Stack Overflow. This way your answer will stay complete as long as SO is around.

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking about space efficiency

Comment: That's a good point, but link decay is more of a problem:) That's also the reason why link-only answers are unaccepted.

Answer (score 1):

The X matrix returned by meshgrid has increasing values of X *in columns, not rows*! For example `[X, Y] = meshgrid(-1:1, 1:3)` returns

```
     [-1  0  1;           [1  1  1;
X  =  -1  0  1;       Y =  2  2  2;
   =  -1  0  1];           3  3  3];
```

Note how the x-index should be put in the column of X or Y, and the y-index should be put in the row. Specifically, your line:

```
fGrad = [ xGrad(idx,idy) , yGrad(idx,idy) ]; %gradient's definition
```

should instead be:

```
fGrad = [ xGrad(idy,idx) , yGrad(idy,idx) ]; %gradient's definition
```

The `idy` variable should index the *row*, and `idx` variable should index the *column*

Comment: I can see why I wrote it wrong, but when I tried your solution it still didn't work (it did on `X.^2+Y.^2`, but not on `-20*(X/2-X.^2-Y.^5)*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2)`)

Comment: I think the problem there isn't a straight coding issue, rather more complicated issues with numerical optimization. That problem is [deeply not-convex](http://www.mattgunn.com/delme_opt.png) unless you put some restrictions on it.

Comment: If you look at the graph, there are local minima all over the place.

Comment: I guess this is why our tutor let us work in [-3,3], I cannot see why it converged to the point it did: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-211115-000414.php

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to solve the problem, I just wrote it anew using symbols. Happy convergence: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-211115-075922.php
Many thanks to anyone who helped

Comment: @OdedSayar if Matthew's answer solved your problem, please consider marking his answer as accepted. If you solved it on your own, then consider adding your own answer and accepting that (after 48 hours), to show that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, I did not directly get an answer, but rather found another way to write the algorithm. I'll copy it here and mark it as an answer as you suggested.